# Any easier ways to get the current datestamp

Tags: go

I have this code here but I don't think it's elegant. In fact I think it's kind of messy. Does anyone have a better/cleaner/concise code than this? I just need the timestamp of the day.

```
package main

import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "time"
        "strconv"
)

const (
        layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
        layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
)

func main() {
        year, month, day := time.Now().Date()

        dayStr := strconv.Itoa(day)
        if len(dayStr) == 1 {
                dayStr = "0"+dayStr
        }

        mthStr := strconv.Itoa(int(month))
        if len(mthStr) == 1 {
                mthStr = "0"+mthStr
        }
        layout := strconv.Itoa(year)+"-"+mthStr+"-"+dayStr

        fmt.Printf("%v\n",layout)

        t, err := time.Parse(layoutISO, layout)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(t.Unix())
}
```

Comment: Use `func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time` passing your `year`, `month`, and `day` and everything else set to 0.

Comment: But to answer your question, it's unclear exactly what you want. I would agree that your function is kind of messy. But what is your desired output? Most likely [Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) is all you need, but without knowing the goal, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @Marc how? what's the code like? it's still like mine right/

Comment: No, call `time.Date(...)` after you get the day, month, and year. Then call `.Unix()` on the output. Skip all the string building and parsing.

Comment: @Marc isnt that exactly how my code is written? can you show the code of how to skip all the string building and parsing?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer @Marc suggested. Thanks.

```
    fmt.Printf("Value = %v\n",time.Date(year, month, day, 0,0,0,0, time.UTC).Unix())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're asking, but here are some ways to get the current date and time information.

```
fmt.Println("current date and time:", time.Now().Format("2 January 2006 15:04:05"))
fmt.Println("current time:", time.Now().Format("15:04:05"))
fmt.Println("current date:", time.Now().Format("2 January 2006"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/U2PKjivNzXa